# Python - close windows if exists in order in tkinter

Tags: python, class, tkinter, window, try-except

```
    from tkinter import *

class Main(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)   
        self.parent = parent        
        self.initUI()
    def initUI(self):
        global canvas
        self.parent.title('Python')
        self.pack(fill = BOTH, expand = 1)
        canvas = Canvas(self)
        self.Label_My = Label(self, text = 'MyObject')
        self.Label_My.place(x = 0, y = 0)

        canvas.pack(fill = BOTH, expand = 1)
        canvas.update()
class Main2(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)   
        self.parent = parent        
        self.initUI()
    def initUI(self):
        global canvas
        self.parent.title('Python')
        self.pack(fill = BOTH, expand = 1)
        canvas = Canvas(self)
        self.Label_My = Label(self, text = 'MyObject2')
        self.Label_My.place(x = 0, y = 0)

    canvas.pack(fill = BOTH, expand = 1)
    canvas.update()

root = Tk()
ex = Main(root)
root.geometry('700x500')

root2 = Tk()
ex2 = Main2(root2)
root2.geometry('500x500')

def d():
    if root2:
        root2.destroy()
    if root:
        root.destroy()
```

I created two tkinter window and I am going to close them if they exists, but it print the "root/root2" is not defined if I don't create them as windows.

Also, I find that I have to close "root" first in order. 
If I close "root2" first it prints "pythonw.exe has stopped working"

My solution is to add "try-except-statement" before "if rootx", but I want a better solution.

Comment: Can you show us the complete code -- definitions for ```Main``` and ```Main2```? Where does ```d()``` get invoked?

Comment: You cannot expect a tkinter program with two root windows to work the way you think it will. A tkinter program needs to have exactly one root window -- that's why it's called the _root_ window. If you need more than one window, create instances of `Toplevel`.

Comment: I showed all my code now.

Answer (score 0):

Add your windows to a list as you create them, then destroy the windows in the order that you added them.

```
windows = []

root = Tk()
ex = Main(root)
root.geometry('700x500')
windows.append(root)

root2 = Tk()
ex2 = Main2(root2)
root2.geometry('500x500')
windows.append(root2)

def d():
    for window in windows:
        window.destroy()
```